# Using message.channel.send in uncaughtException event

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want the uncaughtException and unhandledRejection events to log errors and send the error message in the same channel where the command was executed

function:

```js
function ErrorLog(errortext, message) {
    const ErrorEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(`#${config["color"].error}`)
        .setDescription(`${errortext}`)
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [ErrorEmbed] })
    return
}
```

event:

```js
process.on("unhandledRejection", ({ err, message }) => {
    ErrorLog(`An unknown and unexpected error has occurred! \`\`\`${err}\`\`\``, message)
    console.log(`An unknown and unexpected error has occurred! ${err}`);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

However, it gives me an error saying `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')`, and I'm not exactly sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply use `try catch`

```
try{
//your code
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error)
        message.channel.send({content: error})
    }
```

Comment: Make sure that the error is a string first:
`message.channel.send(typeof error === 'string' ? error : 'An error occured')`